# How can I declare a global function to call an Angular service from the browser console?

Tags: javascript, angular

We have a requirement that we'd like to develop a "mini" testing framework for use within our Angular application. The point of the framework is to be able to manipulate API calls to alter the response body and status code in order to trip various error handlers within our application and make sure the application is responding correctly to errored API calls.

To do this I have been researching how to call Angular services from outside of Angular. [This article](https://stribny.name/blog/2018/01/how-to-communicate-with-angular-components-outside-angular) describes how it is possible to create a service and then trigger it from outside Angular by calling the `window.fireAngularEvent('sampleEventName', args)` function.

However when I tried to do this via the browser, I get the following: `Uncaught TypeError: window.fireAngularEvent is not a function`

Here is my Angular service

```
export class GlobalApiTestingFrameworkService {

  constructor() {
    window['fireAngularEvent'] = (eventName, args) => {
      console.log('fireAngularEvent : ' + eventName + ' : ' + args);
    }
  }
}
```

What do I need to do to be able to call the window.fireAngularEvent function? Do I need to define it outside of Angular within its own JS file? If so, what exactly do I include within the function body to allow it to communicate with the service? The article I linked isn't very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to the **space** in `window['fireAngularEvent ']` replace the defintion with `window['fireAngularEvent']` and you'll be able to call window.fireAngularEvent without any issue.

Make sure that your service is instantiated at least one time.

To be sure You can use for example your service in AppComponent like that:

```
export class AppComponent  {
    constructor(private globalApiTestingFrameworkService: GlobalApiTestingFrameworkService){
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry no that isn't the issue, that was just a copy and paste problem. My actual code doesn't have the space.

Comment: @Jake12342134 Is your service instantiated at least one time ? Did you add it as a provider in any module ?

Comment: Yes, it's provided within the app.module

Comment: Does it need to be provided and instantiated?

Comment: Yes it needs to be instantiated at least once so the constructor will be called, check my updated answer

Comment: This was the issue, I had not instantiated the service in my app.component.ts.